# Mongo (Cloud) + Vue.js - Está certo ou errado?

Tags: vue.js

Olá,

Eu estou programando um aplicativo usando o Vue.JS, (sou novato na área Javascript) e o Mongo (Servidor Cloud) e queria tirar uma dúvida para saber se a minha lógica está correta ou errada, e se preciso melhorar...

Quando o usuário faz login, eu salvo os dados do usuário pelo localStorage, dessa forma:

```
    methods() {
     let api = 'localhost:3000/api/login';
      axios.post(api, {
       email: email,
       password: password
     })
      .then((res) => {
       var useruid = res.uid;
       localStorage.setItem('logado', useruid);
       this.$router.push('/dashboard');
      });
}
```

É assim que programei o meu aplicativo. Está certo o meu código?

Comment: Certo de qual forma? Não vejo sentido em usar `get` para login, como o servidor vai saber quais as credenciais do usuário?

Comment: É post, eu acabei adicionando get em lugar errado. Editei o post, se puder responder agradeço. Abç

Comment: Para salvar em localstorage após o login está certo, precisa configurar depois o `logoff`, validar também se a pessoa está realmente logada no backend para não ver a tela do sistema mesmo o servidor mandando um `403`